# manage dns records via bind9 without restarting the server

Tags: dns

At my office we setup and teardown VMs regularly (testing, etc). Currently we have no choice to but complain to IT to get a dns entry added for the VM (testapp.myoffice.com, for example) or memorize the IP of the new VM. I'd like to to allow us devs to get a web address that would redirect to the VM of their choice.

I've done some reading and it looks like Bind9 is a good starting point: I can add my own dns entries and fallback to another dns entry, but I have some questions:

1. can bind9 (or another service) have entries added while its running or does it require manual shutdown, updating, and restarting? The goal is to have a webapp that users can enter a VM ip and get a bitly-style link out of it.
2. how can I let other users access these dns entries without having to specify the dns host? my goal is to have anyone in our network be able to type in the generated url and have it redirect to the server, but not just an http redirect.

I'm still learning about dns stuff and I'm not even sure if I'm going about it the right way; any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Without shutdown, updating, and restarting? You mean, like `rndc reload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First to answer your questions about bind9  (I have not used it in the way you are talking about for many years, so I could be remebering wrong, or things might have changed):

Bind9 can be reloaded with entires (assuming you modify the configuration) without downtime.  You can, from memory, set up a master/slave system where zones are fed to the slave without downtime.   I don't believe that interfacing this stuff with BIND is trivial.

That said, I believe there are a number of better (and easier) way of doing this.  The way I would probably do it is this -

1. Set up either a new domain name or a subdomain, and have the NS records pointed to a new
   server/virtual server which will manage the domain names for that domain (and, of-course
   the dev system names will be under this domain)
2. Set up an authorative nameserver which interfaces with Postgres or MySQL and simply do
   the updates in SQL - the changes will flow through automatically - you will probably
   want to run relatively low (60 seconds ?) TTL's so old information times out quickly.
   A couple of simple DNS servers which you should lookat are [MyDNS](http://mydns.bboy.net/) and [Power DNS](https://www.powerdns.com/)

There are some alternative ways of doing this.   If you use (or can change to) DNSMasq, you can configure DNSMasq to feed entries from the HOSTS file into the DNS, and then you only need to maintain the hosts file on the DNSMasq server with the appropriate IP address.

You might want to look at some kind of Dynamic DNS service.  This will allow you to update the machines DNS reference without running a nameserver, I assume you would need public facing IP's, and,of-course, this leaks internal information onto the wider Internet and may not be appropriate.

A totally different approach might be to forget about doing it in DNS and set up a "reverse proxy" which forwards on the the appropriate machine - in that way you configure the reverse proxy whenever you make changes, but as long as the reverse proxy remains the same you can always update it.  You will either need to hack the code to do this, or manually modify the IP address.   I am aware there are at least 2, but probably a lot more ways of doing this.  One is to use Apache + mod_proxy, another is to configure Squid.  The key word to google for here would be "Reverse Proxy"

Comment: Oh man, that's a lot of info. I'm gonna go through it and if it looks like mydns or powerdns or a reverse proxy will do what I want, I'll quickly accept this. Thanks!

Comment: My coworker in IT has set up something called [tinyDNS](http://cr.yp.to/djbdns/tinydns-data.html) which looks like it'll do what I want. Thanks for this response though!